# Changing a value in a asp-route

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

With the code below is there a way to check if VendorName is not null and if so then asp-route-VendorName should be empty, the reason why I am asking is sometimes VendorName can be NULL and therefore the ToUpper() will fail. Hoping I can just do a conditional asp-route-VendorName

```
            <a class="nav-item" asp-page="./Index" asp-route-VendorName="@vendor.VendorName.ToUpper()">
            <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vendor.VendorName)</i>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IOutboundParmeterTransformer` for this task (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/route-parameter-transformers). Create a class like this:

```
public class UpperCaseParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object value)
    {
        return value?.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Register it with the ServiceContainer:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("uppercase", typeof(UpperCaseParameterTransformer));
});
```

Then apply it to a route value in the route template for the page:

```
@page "{VendorName:uppercase}"
```

That way, the routing system will take care of automatically converting any route parameter value to upper case.